# Multi-Class Classification in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, weka, libsvm

I am trying to implement Multiclass classification in WEKA.
I have lot of rows, say bank transactions, and one is tagged as Food,Medicine,Rent,etc. I want to develop a classifier which can be trained with the previous data I have and predict the class it can belong to for future transactions. If I am right this is Multiclass and not multilabel since each transaction can belong to only one class.

Below are a few algorithms I am considering

1. Naive Bayes
2. Multinomial Logistic Regression
3. Multiclass SVM
4. Max Entropy
5. Neural Networks (if possible)

In my data Number of features <<< Number of transactions and hence I am thinking of one vs rest binary classifier instead of one vs one.

1. Are there any other algorithms I should lok into which will help with my goal?
2. Is there any algos that I put are useless for my goal?

Also,I found that scikit-learn in Python is better than WEKA but I can run scikit-learn only on one processor. Is this true?

Answers to any question would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Many scikit-learn classifiers and also cross-validation schemes support embarrassingly parallelism by just setting `n_jobs=` to the number of cores you want to use. It also ships with `joblib`, with which you can parallelize anything else manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at RandomForest which is a well known classifier and quite efficient.

In scikit-learn, you have some class that can be used over several core like RandomForestClassifier. It has a constructor parameter that can be used to define the number of core or a value that will use every available core. Look at the documentation, constructor that contains n_jobs parameter can be used over several core

Comment: [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) can be used on several core.

Comment: If this answers your question don't hesitate to accept it